# installed latest version of node -- but npm is broken (mac)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

OK so, I went to the nodejs.org webpage, downloaded node version 7.5.0, installed it using the easy to use wizard.
It installed with no errors or issues.
When I open up my terminal, `node -v` gives me `v7.5.0`, and `npm -v` gives me `3.6.0`.
Obviously I want the latest version of npm, so I go to `npm install npm@latest -g`, but I get this error:

```
Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
```

In fact, trying to install ANYTHING using npm results in the same error.
How do I fix npm?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9377

Comment: You can just use `npm up -g` to update the `npm` version...

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling your current node version and reinstall using `nvm` or `brew`:

To find where node lives: `command -v node && command -v npm`

Remove these directories as stated in some of the comments here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9377

---

Posting this for anyone passing by. You can use `npm up -g` to update the `npm` version. Here's output from my console installing node `4.7.3` via `nvm`:

```
user@localhost:~/Desktop/demo$ nvm install 4.7.3
Downloading and installing node v4.7.3...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.7.3/node-v4.7.3-darwin-x64.tar.gz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Computing checksum with shasum -a 256
Checksums matched!
Now using node v4.7.3 (npm v2.15.11)
user@localhost:~/Desktop/demo$ npm up -g
/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.7.3/bin/npm -> /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.7.3/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@4.2.0 /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.7.3/lib/node_modules/npm
user@localhost:~/Desktop/demo$ npm -v
4.2.0
user@localhost:~/Desktop/demo$
```